# Dynamic save of Multidimensional Array Elements alternately by position in Python

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array:

```
   array =  [[900, 650, 0, 0, 2, 1, 24, 3, 4, 25, 0, 29, 407, 268, 565, 54, 3, 1, 1, 0, 3, 1], [1001, 7062, 0, 0, 0, 1, 20, 3, 4, 26, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 50, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1]]
```

I want to save this  2-dimensional alternately, so first the first element of the first array, than the first element of the second array, than the second element of the first array, than the second element of the second array and so on..
How can I solve this dynamically? So independent from consisting of 2 Arrays in this case? Lets say I have 3 array in this list. I want to have the first element of the first array, than the first element of the second array, than the first element of the third array, than the second element of the first array and so on..
Logic:

```
array[firstArray][firstElement]
array[secondArray][firstElement]
array[thirdArray][firstElement]
array[firstArray][secondElement]
array[secondArray][secondElement]
array[thirdArray][secondElement]

....
```

I tried it with 2 for loops but I get an index out ouf range error.

Comment: _"I tried it with 2 for loops but I get an index out ouf range error."_: Show your code as a [mre]. Ask a specific question about your code. Without your code, it just seems like you're getting the internet to do your work for you, which isn't nice. [ask]; [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's precisely [[Python.Docs]: Built-in Functions - zip(*iterables)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)'s purpose:

> ```py
> >>> from pprint import pprint as pp
> >>>
> >>> arr = [[900, 650, 0, 0, 2, 1, 24, 3, 4, 25, 0, 29, 407, 268, 565, 54, 3, 1, 1, 0, 3, 1], [1001, 7062, 0, 0, 0, 1, 20, 3, 4, 26, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 50, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1]]  # Your array
> >>>
> >>> transp = [list(i) for i in zip(*arr)]
> >>>
> >>> pp(transp)
> [[900, 1001],
>  [650, 7062],
>  [0, 0],
>  [0, 0],
>  [2, 0],
>  [1, 1],
>  [24, 20],
>  [3, 3],
>  [4, 4],
>  [25, 26],
>  [0, 0],
>  [29, 0],
>  [407, 0],
>  [268, 0],
>  [565, 0],
>  [54, 50],
>  [3, 0],
>  [1, 0],
>  [1, 0],
>  [0, 2],
>  [3, 0],
>  [1, 1]]
> >>>
> >>> arr0 = [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 0, 1]]  # Demo array
> >>>
> >>> transp0 = [list(i) for i in zip(*arr0)]
> >>>
> >>> pp(transp0)
> [[0, 4, 8], [1, 5, 9], [2, 6, 0], [3, 7, 1]]
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much man! I did not know about this zip function. I used it and created the tupel. But I needed one array not tuples so I transformed the tuple in one array. THANKS!

Comment: If it's a list of tuples then it's even simpler: `[i for i in zip(*arr)]`. You're welcome!

Answer (score 3):

I hope I understood you correctly. You need another one-dimensional array from a two-dimensional one. I can offer you this code (I could have made a mistake, because I wrote it on the phone). The argument `A` is how many arrays are there in your array:

```
def onearray(array, a):
    z = 0
    n = 0
    while sum([len(array[i]) for i in range(a)]) < n:
        for i in range(a):
            if len(array[i]) > z:
                newarray.append(array[i][z])
                n += 1
        z += 1
    return newarray
```